# jquery button to uncheck checkboxes

Tags: jquery, button, unchecked

This task seemed to be very easy, though my code doesn't work.

I have table with some rows, each row has a checkbox, underneath I put button "Remove all" to uncheck checkboxes.

This is my code:

```
    $('#remove-button').click(function(){
        $('input:checked').prop('checked',false);
        //e.stopPropagation(); // I tried also with this
        // $('input:checked').removeAttr('checked'); // or this syntax
    });
```

When i click on the button, all inputs are unchecked but this is not happen due to my code because when I comment this snippet, it also happens when I click on the button. I also see that when I click and inputs are unchecked my website seems to refresh because page scrools up.

I also add another button to checked inputs:

```
    $('#add-button').click(function(e){
        $('input').prop('checked',true);
        //e.stopPropagation(); // I tried also with this
        // $('input:checked').removeAttr('checked'); // or this syntax
    });
```

When I fire this inputs are checked and in a second my website refreshes and everything disappear.

I use the newest Firefox and Chrome, and jQuery - 1.11 (but checked also with 1.8.0 and 1.7.1).

There is also atatched

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: Also attached css file href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.4.2/pure-min.css

Comment: what's the type of your buttons? are they type of "submit"

Comment: No, those are buttons without type attribute but I also tried with type="submit"

Comment: can you paste your html code including form tag and all your buttons

Comment: Your code is working for me check http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/x9eDE/. Do you wrap script at `document.ready`?

Comment: My code works now with e.preventDefault(), but I found one more problem. If any input is checked the tr background is also changed and when unchecked the "remove-button" is disabled. How to managed to makes those two buttons (add/remove) works together, I mean:
 - when click add and then remove, the Remove-button should disappear as it is after document ready. For now add andd remove works but after sequence add --> remove, the remove button doesn't disappear

Comment: It should works together, maybe you have another code that disables remove-button?

Comment: //on/off remove-button while checkbox is checked
            var checkBoxes = $(':checkbox');
            checkBoxes.change(function () {
            $('#remove-button').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
            });
            checkBoxes.change();

Comment: Ok now everything is ok, thx guys!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'checked' property is boolean but it means when it not exists it is false.
If you need not submit on click or don't go to link there is `e.preventDefault()`.
So you need this:

```
 $('#remove-button').click(function(e) {
    $('input:checked').removeAttr('checked');
    e.preventDefault();
 });
 $('#add-button').click(function(e) {
   var input = $('input.input-to-check')
   input.attr('checked', 'checked');
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: you save my life. thank's.